# h2o4gpu Dockerfils - CentOS vs Runtime and Starting Image

Tags: docker, h2o

I have been working with building the h2o4gpu Docker image, and after getting through the build process for the CentOS image, have found myself with a few more questions:

1. What is the difference between the Dockerfile_runtime, and Dockerfile-build-centos.x86-64-centos7-cuda9.0? Near as I can tell, the Dockerfile_runtime is intended for an Ubuntu image, but is there a preferred one to use?
2. After building the Centos Dockerfile, I have been using the below code to try and run it:

   Docker run -it --rpm -p 8888:8888 dockerimage

When I do, I get the error:

```
Error response from daemon: oci runtime error: container linux.go:247: starting container process caused "exec \"./run.sh\": stat ./run.sh: no such file or directory
```

I did try adding in the included run.sh file, partially since I saw that it was included in the Dockerfile_runtime:

```
COPY run.sh /run.sh
ENTRYPOINT ["./run.sh"]
CMD ["/run.sh]
```

However, this didn't have any visible changes on the output, so I've been scratching my head what to do next.

I appreciate any insight or thoughts offered!

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> What is the difference between the Dockerfile_runtime, and Dockerfile-build-centos.x86-64-centos7-cuda9.0?

The `build` dockerfiles (we have 2) are intended to only contain things required to build the project, whereas the runtime one also contains stuff required by the project during runtime, adds some sample data and starts a Jupyter notebook. The Centos one was added as the binaries generated by the Ubuntu image cannot run on quite a few Linux distros easily (due to high glibc version used by Ubuntu). We have a PR which rewrites all our dockers as Centos based but still need to test it more before merging.

> but is there a preferred one to use?

For building the `whl` either `Dockerfile-build` or the Centos one are ok. If you want a runtime docker then `Dockefile-runtime` is prefered.

> After building the Centos Dockerfile

How are you building it? You can have a look at our docker building scripts how we do it https://github.com/h2oai/h2o4gpu/blob/master/scripts/make-docker-runtime.sh There should be no need to add that `run.sh` file as it's being copied in the dockerfile. The Centos docker file does not start Jupyter, expose 8888 nor contain `run.sh`.